# Frontend Logging

Tags: logging, apache-kafka, next.js, frontend

I have a NextJS frontend with a Python Flask backend. I'm interested in configuring frontend logging. My development team is using AWS as our cloud provider. We are looking for a scalable solution for frontend logging. Some options we are exploring are (including but not limited to):

1. AWS Cloudwatch
2. Apache Kafka
3. Sentry

From what I've seen, it seems that Apache Kafka is a scalable, low cost big data solution for logging. I have the following question:

1. If my team chooses to go with Kafka for our logging solution, is there any easy web-based interface to query kafka logs with simple SQL syntax? It seems like a solution like Lenses involves you having to install software on your laptop, which I'm trying to avoid

Answer (score 0):

Kafka is a backend technology. It's not recommended to expose it to the open internet for frontend Javascript to write to. Plus, Kafka has no REST API to make that possible without extra tools.

For example, Divollte is one solution.

ksqlDB, SparkSQL, Flink SQL, Presto, Hive, etc all exist for querying Kafka data using SQL

Comment: so what do you recommend as a good low cost, scalable, easy solution for logging frontend events?

Comment: I'm not a frontend developer. And asking for libraries is off topic for Stackoverflow. Did you look at Divollte collector?